# How do I java regex find and replace

Tags: java, regex

What's the regex for removing parentheses and everything between?

```
input  = "hello world (this is a test1) (test 2) hello";
output = "hello world   hello";
```

I tried:

```
str.replaceAll("//(.*?//)", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using forward slash characters to escape the `(` and `)` special characters. You need to use backslashes:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "");
```